# Hiding menu java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to hide one of this drop down menu when the user is log-in or log-out, I use `$_Session` to know if the user is logged in. Something is wrong with my JavaScript. Hope anyone could help. Thanks !!Here is my code:

The two drop down menu i want to hide/show:

```
<li class="dropdown" id="account" >
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Account
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>

  <li class="dropdown" id="user">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
          echo ' '.htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }
      ?>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
        $('#user').show();
        $('#account').hide();
    } else {
        $('#user').hide();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: PHP is not JavaScript

Comment: why not only echo it if the user is logged in, instead of show\hide js

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Suppose i could echo a menu i want. But my problem is that one of the menu is partially hide(#user) and the showed menu(#account) is replaced when a user login. Could i initially show #account then replace it with #user if a user is log-in in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP to include a class on the div you want this way you might not need javascript and/or jQuery

```
<li class="dropdown <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo "notvisible";} ?>" id="account" >
```

And use the class with CSS to set

```
.notvisible { display:none; }
```

You can also use a .toggleclass() or other means of hiding/showing menu afterward if you want.

Another way would be to echo the menu you want with PHP eg:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo "<li class=\"dropdown\" id=\"account>\"" >>> and whatever you want
    } else {
        echo "<li class=\"dropdown\" id=\"account\">" Hello user".$_SESSION['username']."And whatever else"
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried using your 1st answer but it doesn't work. Could you consider "notvisible" as a class? But anyway my question is already answered. I tried to use PHP inside my javascript file which is a taboo *lol*. My solution is to write it all using PHP alone. I think i need to read more on java script. Thanks btw :).

Comment: @Leroux In HTML a class is more or less a name/identifier that you make up and use to identify and select elements in the HTML code. It is mostly used with javascript/jQuery or with CSS to style elements. It replace inline styling such <a style="color:#fff"> with  <style>.white {color:#fff;}</style> <a class="white">A</a> or a CSS file which allows easy styling of many elements. An element can have any number also <a class="white strong wide big bacon">A</a>